# Insert current timestamp using javascript in database using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am trying to insert local time into database using javascript. Can any one help me?
could you please have a look on the file named member.class.php and please let me know where I have to put the javascript code... `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lfef67brewx7rub/wYRP72bDh7`

Comment: Actually I have tried with php script but I am not that much familiar with javascript

Comment: A little bit of code could help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple man...try with this

```
var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
```

it will give you time in milli seconds or you can use like

```
new Date().getTime();
```

if you want it in unix(linux) timestamp then use like this

```
var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);   it will also give you in seconds
```

Comment: What about date and time together? and I am trying to store it in linux platform in web host...

Comment: could you please have a look on the file named member.class.php and please let me know where I have to put the javascript code... `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lfef67brewx7rub/wYRP72bDh7`

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript:

```
    var d = new Date();
    var date_with_time = d.getDate()+"-"
                        +d.getMonth()+1+"-"
                        +d.getFullYear()+" "
                        +d.getHours()+" "
                        +d.getMinutes()+" "
                        +d.getSeconds();
```

In PHP, the best way will be that you should create your `time` column `DATETIME` type and set default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. No need to manually insert it through Javascript.

Comment: after setting current_timestamp the value is inserting the servers current time... but I want to insert my local regions time

Comment: could you please have a look on the file named member.class.php and please let me know where I have to put the javascript code... `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lfef67brewx7rub/wYRP72bDh7`

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime = "Date n Tym : " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
            + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
            + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
            + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
            + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
            + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

[10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/1791115)!

Answer (score 0):

DB like time stamp in js:

```
var timestamp = "" + d.getFullYear()
                    + ("0" + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
                    + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-"
                    + ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2)
                    + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
                    + ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

after this, for example, timestamp="20160408-134304"